# Binding Angularjs select items to model using property of item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a collection as follows:

```
$scope.TeamType = [
    {
        "name": "Beginner",
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Novice",
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Expert",
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Masters",
        "value": 3
    }];
```

I also have a variable in my controller:

```
$scope.SelectedTeamType = 0;
```

I am trying to use these items in the following statement

```
<select ng-model="SelectedTeamType" ng-options="v as v.name for v in TeamType track by v.value"></select>
```

I would like the select to init with the corresponding value in the model and save the value to the model when select changes. I am not sure why the model SelectedTeamType is getting the entire object stored to it instead of the v.value and why it isnt initializing with beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment *I need to keep $scope.SelectedTeamType as an integer value*

Use

```
<select 
    ng-model="SelectedTeamType" 
    ng-options="v.value as v.name for v in TeamType"
 ></select>
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MUnfIsPgpbncy6frwF4e?p=preview)

Its storing object due to expression which you have provided in [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

You need to bind object, use

```
$scope.SelectedTeamType = $scope.TeamType[0];
```

better

```
$scope.SelectedTeamType = $scope.TeamType.filter(function(t) {
    return t.value == 0;
});
```

Comment: I need to keep $scope.SelectedTeamType as an integer value

Comment: @user3648646, then simply use `v.value as v.name for v in TeamType` in ng-options refer `select as label for value in array` in docs